# Can a Mybatis mapper XML configuration be included in another mapper configuration?

Tags: ibatis, mybatis

What I want to do is put various `<sql>...</sql>` blocks in a Shared.xml file and then have more specific files include them.

Something like this:

**mybatis-config.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <mappers>
        <mapper resource="Shared.xml"/>
        <mapper resource="Custom1.xml"/>
        <mapper resource="Custom2.xml"/>
        <mapper resource="Custom3.xml"/>
    </mappers>
</configuration>
```

**Shared.xml**

```
<mapper namespace="com.company.SharedMapper">       
    <sql id="someSQL">
        SELECT 1;
    </sql>          
</mapper>
```

**Custom1.xml**

```
<mapper namespace="com.company.CustomMapper1">      
    <select id="getSomeData" resultMap="CustomResultMap">
        <include refid="someSQL"/>
    </select>               
</mapper>
```

Obviously this is a very simplified version of what I want but hopefully it's enough to describe what I am going for.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, that is supported. In case the dependant xml is read first MyBatis will retry again when the rest of xml pieces are loaded.